# How to convert an Excel formula in to JavaScript for an Adobe Form

Tags: javascript, excel, pdf

I have created a PDF form, but I need it to work out a price based on the input in a "formfield" (QTY1.1) so in Excel cell D20 represents QTY1.1

```
=IF(D20<5, D20*29, IF(D20<11, D20*28, IF(D20<21, D20*27, D20*26)))
```

Is anyone able to help me out with the JavaScript code?

I got as far as:

```
(event.value = ( this.getField("QTY1.1").value * 29)
```

Which works but only when I multiply the value by 29.

Comment: Attempt to understand what the Excel formula does (in words, not with references to other cells), and then you should be able to recreate that in (Acrobat) JavaScript. In other words, do a proper analysis based on what is done in the Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: The Excel syntax seems to be `if (condition) then ARG1 else ARG2`. From then on, it's simply more nested if's.